# Oracle SQL - Multiple rows into one field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like this:

[image]

I need a query (no PL/SQL) that shows this output:

[image]

So for each **Product ID** I want the distinct values of **Delivery Type** in the field **Delivery Type**.

Is there a way to get this result through a "simple" query in Oracle?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `listagg` after getting the distinct delivery types per product id. (Note that there is a 4000 character limit for the aggregated string.)

```
select product_id,listagg(delivery_type,'/') within group (order by delivery_type)
from (select distinct product_id,delivery_type from tbl) t
group by product_id
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked perfectly